React-big-calendar - display multiple timeslots in week, workweek and day view
I am using React-big-calendar in my react app. I want to have the ability to display two timeslots in different timezones (i.e. these are configurable) in the day, workweek and week view, similar to the outlook. Refer below image.

I checked the documentation, but I found ways to format the timeslot but not to add another column. Please let me know if there is any workaround for this.
